# How to handle 204 errow from window.location = 'URL'

Tags: javascript, download, handle, window.location

I'm trying to export file in such way:

```
exportReportFile: function exportReportFile(url) {
    window.location = url;
}
```

But sometimes I have 204 error. How can I handle it?

Comment: Can you please provide more context to the question please.

Comment: Hello. I'm working on functionality for downloading exports from back-end.
I'm downloading files in such way window.location = url;
Some of methods are returning 204 error and I must handle it.
 window.location = url; is not common http request with success and fail callbacks. I don't know how to handle this error.

Answer (score 0):

This means that the URL that you pass to the function is returning a 204 error.

Comment: That's not an answer. You just said obvious. I asked how to handle this error.